Indirect Concavity of $e^{\min \left\{x_1, x_2\right\}}$
$\textbf{Definition:}$ A function $f$ is said to be indirectly concave [convex] if there exist functions $F$ and $h$ such that $F$ is concave [convex], $h$ is increasing, and $f = h \circ F$.
It is clear that a function can be both indirectly concave and convex, for instance by taking $F$ as the linear function and $h$ as an increasing function.
I am wondering whether $e^{\min\{x_1, x_2\}}$ is indirectly concave or not. It is obviously indirectly convex since $e^x \circ \min\{x_1, x_2\} = e^{\min\{x_1, x_2\}}$ and the $\min$ function is convex. So, what can I say about it being indirectly concave?

I guess the function $\min(x_1,x_2)$ is considered on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

@RyszardSzwarc, yes.

The comments indicate that the function $\exp(\min(x_1,x_2))$ is indirectly concave. The question remains if this function can be indirectly convex. Assume by contradiction $$\exp(\min(x_1,x_2))= h\circ F(x_1,x_2) $$ where $F(x_1,x_2)$ is convex and $h$ is  increasing. Then $$(h^{-1}\circ \exp )(\min(x_1,x_2))=F(x_1,x_2).$$ Denote $g=h^{-1}\circ \exp.$ Then $g$ is increasing and $g(\min(x_1,x_2))=F(x_1,x_2).$ Let $x_1=0,x_2=2$ and $x_1'=2, x_2'=0.$ Then
$$g(1)=g\left (\min\left ({1\over 2}(x_1+x_1'),{1\over 2}(x_2+x'_2) \right )\right )=F\left ({1\over 2}(x_1+x_1'),{1\over 2}(x_2+x'_2) \right )\\ g(0)={1\over 2}g(\min(x_1,x_2))+{1\over 2}g(\min(x_1',x_2'))={1\over 2}F(x_1,x_2)+{1\over 2}F(x_1',x_2')$$ As $g(1)>g(0)$ the function $F(x_1,x_2)$ is not convex.
Remark It may occur that a nonlinear function $f(x_1,x_2)$ is simultaneously indirectly convex and indirectly concave. Indeed, assume a function $u(x_1,x_2)$ satisfies $u(x_1,x_2)=v(x_1-x_2)$ for a function $v.$ It is obvious that $u$ is convex iff $v$ is convex and   $u$ is concave iff $v$ is concave. Let $v(x)=x+e^x$ and $\widetilde{v}=x-e^{-x}.$ Both functions are increasing with the range equal $\mathbb{R}.$ Morever $v$ is convex while $\widetilde{v}$ is concave. Let $g=\widetilde{v}\circ v^{-1}.$ Then $g$ is increasing and $g\circ v=\widetilde{v}.$ Hence $g\circ u=\widetilde{u}$ where $u(x_1,x_2)=v(x_1-x_2)$ and $\widetilde{u}(x_1,x_2)=\widetilde{v}(x_1-x_2).$ Thus the function $\widetilde{u}$ is concave and indirectly convex.

Actually the min function $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$; $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is concave, and thus $e^{\min\{x_1,x_2\}}$ is indirectly concave.
Indeed, to show that $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$; $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is concave as claimed, it suffices to show that the inequality $\min\{\lambda a +(1-\lambda)c, \lambda b+(1-\lambda)d\}$ $\ge \lambda \min\{a,b\} + (1-\lambda)\min\{c,d\}$ holds, for all real numbers $a,b,c,d$, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. But indeed, on the one hand
$$\lambda a + (1-\lambda)c \ge \lambda \min\{a,b\} + (1-\lambda)\min\{c,d\}$$
[because $a \ge \min\{a,b\}$ and $\lambda \ge 0$ and $c \ge \min\{c,d\}$ and $(1-\lambda) \ge 0$].
Likewise, on the other hand
$$\lambda b + (1-\lambda)d \ge \lambda \min\{a,b\} + (1-\lambda)\min\{c,d\}.$$
[Indeed, both quantities in the "$\min\{\cdot\}$" in the LHS of the above are at least as large as the RHS of the above, thus so must be the minimum of both of these quantities.] Putting these together gives the desired inequality
$$\min \{\lambda a + (1-\lambda, \lambda b + (1-\lambda)d\}$$
$$\ge \lambda \min\{a,b\} + (1-\lambda)\min\{c,d\}.$$
And thus $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$; $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is indeed concave.

One could also argue that $\min(x_1, x_2) = - \max(-x_1, -x_2)$ and it is “well known” that the maximum of two convex functions (here: two linear functions) is again convex.

@Martin R Well, it is just as "well-known" that the minimum of two concave functions is concave, I thought a direct proof would be useful to whomever is not aware of this fact [even if the OP themselves are].

A one line proof can be based on $$2\min(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2-|x_1-x_2|$$ and the fact that $-|x|$ is concave, which is obvious.
